# Testing APScheduler locally with Foreman

Tags: python, heroku, foreman, apscheduler

I use foreman to run my python app locally and test it. This is what I do:

```
foreman start -e local.env
```

I'm trying to add scheduling to my app, so I installed apscheduler and followed the [tutorial on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python). I added this line to my *Procfile*:

```
clock: python clock.py
```

And my *clock.py* looks like this:

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

sched = Scheduler()

@sched.interval_schedule(minutes=1)
def timed_job():
    print 'This job is run every minute.'

@sched.cron_schedule(day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=17)
def scheduled_job():
    print 'This job is run every weekday at 5pm.'

sched.start()
print 'Scheduler started'

while True:
    pass
```

So now, when I start foreman I can see this:

```
11:54:05 web.1   | started with pid 16709
11:54:05 clock.1 | started with pid 16710
11:54:05 web.1   | 2014-01-23 11:54:05 [16709] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
11:54:05 web.1   | 2014-01-23 11:54:05 [16709] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (16709)
11:54:05 web.1   | 2014-01-23 11:54:05 [16709] [INFO] Using worker: sync
11:54:05 web.1   | 2014-01-23 11:54:05 [16713] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16713
```

Looks valid, but now, I'd expect the clock process should log the message every minute, but it's not. Actually I don't get any logs from the clock process, is that normal?

I discovered that when I leave it on for some time and then Ctrl+C I can then see the logs coming from the clock process, but only some:

- One "Scheduler started" message
- Two "This job is run every minute." messages, even when I leave it for longer than 2 minutes

My question is, how can I make the logs be visible live? Or am I misinterpreting this and this behaviour is normal?

**Edit**: After investigating some more, I discovered that I don't get the logs from my *web* process too. I think it's a mixture of foreman and gunicorn that prevented the logs from appearing, so I gave up the gunicorn for development, and I changed my *foreman start* to:

```
foreman run -e local.env python app/myapp.py runserver
```

In the end I gave up on using the clock process as I believe paying for the separate dyno just to run the clock process is a waste of money. Instead I'm using iron worker scheduling which is more than enough for my simple needs.